# Why am I getting a NameError for self.name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a class that will execute some code when an instance of the class is created (without defining a method for the class). However, I want to use the "name" property of the class instance in said code.

This is my code:

```py
class foo:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    print(self.name)

x = foo('it works')
```

Python raises a NameError and says that name 'self' is not defined.

I don't understand what the problem with my code is.

Comment: the main problem here is the indentation, please, fix it

Comment: I was trying to have the print statement inside the class, but outside the __init__.

Comment: @oatless that doesn't make any sense. `self` is just a regular argument, it is a local variable to the method. What instance would `self` refer to in the class scope anyway? The most reasonable way to "create a class that will execute some code when an instance of the class is created" is to put that code in `__init__`. That's what `__init__` is for.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the point was to have some code execute every time an instance of the said class is created. The code to be executed needed to use the variable that was passed to create the instance of the class, hence I needed to use self.name

Comment: @oatless OK... so like I said, you would want to do that in `__init__`, why wouldn't you want to do that in `__init__`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I feel pretty stupid, cause I didn't know I could.

Comment: @oatless a method is just a function (with [a bit of magic](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod) to inject the current instance - canonically named `self``- as first argument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a problem of indentation:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print(self.name)
x = foo('it works')
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have a `self` in the global scope. `self` is only defined within the methods.

So you need to move the print after you've defined `x`, and access `x` rather than `self`.

Comment: This is true, although I think the op was trying to access `self` in the class scope (i.e. class body) instead of the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
self
```

can only be used inside the init method. You need to access it using "name" instead.

Answer (score 0):

**self** needs to be defined inside class definition only. In your code it is outside the class scope. If you want to access the name attribute after creating instance, then the code should be as below:

```
x = foo('it works')
print(x.name)
```

Comment: Actually, the problem is that `self` is being used *in the class scope* where it only exists in the local scope to `__init__`.